# Length and iterate JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting a json through url and i have parsed it. Resultant json is

```
[{                                                                    
"id": "675285"                                                        
,"t" : "BBG"                                                          
,"e" : "ASX"                                                          
,"l" : "0.645"                                                        
,"l_fix" : "0.645"                                                    
,"l_cur" : "A$0.64"                                                   
,"s": "0"                                                             
,"ltt":"4:10PM GMT+11"                                                
,"lt" : "Nov 20, 4:10PM GMT+11"                                       
,"lt_dts" : "2014-11-20T16:10:58Z"                                    
,"c" : "+0.010"                                                       
,"c_fix" : "0.010"                                                    
,"cp" : "1.57"                                                        
,"cp_fix" : "1.575"                                                   
,"ccol" : "chg"                                                       
,"pcls_fix" : "0.635"                                                 
}                                                                     
,{                                                                    
"id": "690577"                                                        
,"t" : "PBG"                                                          
,"e" : "ASX"                                                          
,"l" : "0.515"                                                        
,"l_fix" : "0.515"                                                    
,"l_cur" : "A$0.52"                                                   
,"s": "0"                                                             
,"ltt":"4:11PM GMT+11"                                                
,"lt" : "Nov 20, 4:11PM GMT+11"                                       
,"lt_dts" : "2014-11-20T16:11:05Z"                                    
,"c" : "0.000"                                                        
,"c_fix" : "0.000"                                                    
,"cp" : "0.00"                                                        
,"cp_fix" : "0.000"                                                   
,"ccol" : "chb"                                                       
,"pcls_fix" : "0.515"                                                 
}]
```

Is there anything wrong with this json? I cannot get the length of this json (i.e 2) and having problem in getting value.

Comment: `var array = JSON.parse(thisJSON);
var l = array.length;`

Not work?

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ says that it is valid json, can you post the code that you are validating the data with?

Comment: @benhowdle89 No its not working

Comment: [It does work](http://jsfiddle.net/kagn6L97/)

Comment: @Andy Is this working? Its not working. No output. Is this related to browser?

Comment: Open the console (F12) and you'll see `2` as the last entry.

Comment: [Or look at this instead](http://jsfiddle.net/kagn6L97/1/)

Comment: "Cannot get the length" -- what happens exactly? Show us the code you are using to retrieve and output the length. Any console errors?

Comment: Got the problem.. JSON i am fetching from url is starting with //

Answer (score -1):

json is ok actually.
this works good with your json.

```
var a = JSON.parse('[{"id": "675285","t" : "BBG","e" : "ASX","l" : "0.645","l_fix" : "0.645","l_cur" : "A$0.64","s": "0","ltt":"4:10PM GMT+11","lt" : "Nov 20, 4:10PM GMT+11","lt_dts" : "2014-11-20T16:10:58Z","c" : "+0.010","c_fix" : "0.010","cp" : "1.57","cp_fix" : "1.575","ccol" : "chg","pcls_fix" : "0.635"},{"id": "690577","t" : "PBG","e" : "ASX","l" : "0.515","l_fix" : "0.515","l_cur" : "A$0.52","s": "0","ltt":"4:11PM GMT+11","lt" : "Nov 20, 4:11PM GMT+11","lt_dts" : "2014-11-20T16:11:05Z","c" : "0.000","c_fix" : "0.000","cp" : "0.00","cp_fix" : "0.000","ccol" : "chb","pcls_fix" : "0.515"}]');
alert(a.length);
```